# Co-location: How to be sure the DC does not replace my server

Tags: datacenter, colocation

I'm planning to purchase an expensive server and send it to a datacenter to co-locate.
As this is my first server, there is a question in my mind and would be appreciated if you answer it.
How could I be sure the datacenter will not replace my server with a used (in stock) server? Is there any way such as checking serial number or something else to make sure the server is exactly the one that I sent to DC?

Comment: If you have that little trust in the DC you're sending it to, perhaps you might want to reconsider where you're sending it.

Comment: Actually I have always racked and installed my own systems in the colo center, but a) that seems quite a far-fetched concern b) you can typically read the motherboard serial number, CPU count and installed memory and storage quite easily from any running system

Comment: @HBruijn 
Yes I can check the motherboard s/n but they always can replace the cpu, ram and storage with a used one of same model. do you know any trick to find out they are not replaced?

Comment: @KarenV: Why on earth should anyone do this? What would be the benefit of it? Also, if the DC gets caught with such a stunt, this a guarantee they'll go out of business almost immediately

Comment: @Sven I'm not going to co-locate in a US datacenter so it's not possible for me to physically access the server at any time. That's why I'm a bit concerned

Comment: As Sven mentioned, this should not be an issue, but you could ensure your server is documented in detail by serial number, asset tag, specs, etc, then have it signed by their staff.  Some colos have a form for bringing hardware into their DC.  You should ask them in advance of going on site what your options are.

Comment: If you're never going to physically see the server how do you know whoever you're buying it from is going to supply a new machine and not one cobbled together out of second-hand parts which meet your specs? Or maybe the courier will interfere with it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is silly. A reputable business would not do this. If you have concerns, take it up with the datacenter before signing the contract. This is not a technical problem.

Comment: Most server motherboards have intrusion detection mechanisms.

Comment: Even suppose you find out this happened (which I agree with others above that this seems unlikely), what are you going to do about it? If you have no viable recourse and/or you can't tell the difference anyhow...what's the benefit of having an elaborate detection mechanism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming Linux, you can get many serial numbers with `lshw`:

```
lshw -class memory  
lshw -class disk
```

Other tools exist, like `dmidecode`,`hdparm` etc.

CPU's don't have serial numbers AFAIK, but you could only replace it with the exact same model without you noticing, and this wouldn't make any sense at all (really, the same is true for the rest as well).

Answer (score 0):

So I'm assuming you're not in the US...

First, why did you choose this facility if you're concerned about dishonesty?

Second, the datacenter or co-location facility has no incentive to modify or otherwise alter your system. This is an unreasonable concern.

Third, you should know the specifications of your equipment; RAM, CPU, disk, etc. Request an installation photo after the system is brought online.

Finally, if you need a more reputable co-location firm or US-based assistance, there are resources here on ServerFault that can help with facility recommendations ;)

Comment: If you co-locate your expensive server in a third-world country it become a concern ;) The photo is a good idea. I will ask them for it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

These are good for your imaginary problem, but also if you have several servers and need to collect information for checking warranty, when one fails.

Windows equivalents for getting vendor, model and serialnumber:

```
wmic csproduct get vendor, version
wmic computersystem get model,name,manufacturer,systemtype
wmic bios get serialnumber
```